# Azure Purview - Deleted folders in ADLS2

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-purview

We are scanning ADLS Gen 2 data lake successfully with Purview. However, if a folder is deleted in the lake and you re-scan, the scan does not remove the deleted folder. The deleted folder remains in Purview, but the last modified date (from the scan) remains as the previous scan date/time from when it was present. How can I purge these now invalid entries? Removing the previous scan does not work. Removing the entire source from Purview leaves the scan results behind in the register and a new scan does not clean them up. There is also no manual delete/purge option. The only option seems to be to remove the entire purview account from Azure, redeploy and reconfigure everything.

Am I missing a trick?

Answer (score 0):

Reading to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/concept-detect-deleted-assets this mostly seems like a expected behavior, did you try scanning more than twice post 5mins intervals.

**To keep deleted files out of your catalog, it's important to run regular scans. The scan interval is important, because the catalog can't detect deleted assets until another scan is run.** So, if you run scans once a month on a particular store, the catalog can't detect any deleted data assets in that store until you run the next scan a month later.

Comment: I scanned, deleted and scanned again. Like you say, maybe I need to run a couple of scans post delete but I would expect a scan that doesn't yield a match against a prior should result in a delete. Certainly the scan timestamps show that the two scans found different matches.